# Android sqlite JOIN query with the select columns given by String[]

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have string array with columns I want to select:

```
String[] columns = {"col1", "col2", "col3"};
```

The columns might change in the future, but will always be a subset of available columns.

I cannot find a `SQLiteDatabase` API that lets me pass this array as columns. The only solution I have so far is to just string join the columns with `,` as separator and add it into my query string and perform a `rawQuery`.

Is there a better solution?

**EDIT**

The query is a `JOIN` query.

Comment: When you use the `query` method from `SQLiteQueryBuilder` it has a `projection` parameter. String: A list of which columns to return. Passing null will return all columns, which is discouraged to prevent reading data from storage that isn't going to be used.

Comment: I have heard that `SQLiteQueryBuilder` **can** perform `JOIN`s. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use [`SQLiteQueryBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html).

Add the `JOIN` with [`setTables`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#setTables(java.lang.String)) and pass the String array to `projectionIn` argument of [`query`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#query(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Thanks to @RalphBergmann.

Answer (score 3):

The [`query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) methods in `SQLiteDatabase` take in a `String[] columns` argument which seems to be the thing what you are looking for.

Raw queries with string joining with `,` works, too, and that's basically what `query()` does under the hood.

> Oh, I forgot to mention it involves a JOIN too

Then your best options is probably `rawQuery()` with SQL you're building yourself. Android SQLite wrapper APIs are really not too flexible.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention it involves a `JOIN` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this-

```
ArrayList<String> dynamicColumnList = new ArrayList<>();
//add column dynamically to the list  
String columns[]= dynamicColumnList.toArray(new String[0]);
sqLiteDatabase.query("TableName",columns,"id",new String[]{id},null,null,null);
```